# Is it possible in a drools rule to validate the object fields with another rules?

Tags: drools

The scenario is this:

I have an object X and Y:

```
class X{
   String name;

//setters and getters, etc.
}
class Y{
   String id;
   String name;
   List<X> listOfX;
//setters and getters, etc.
}
```

And on the Drools server(6.4 version). Lets say we have 2 rules:

```
rule "ruleX"
when
    xVariable: X(name==null)
then
    System.out.println( "X name is null" );
end


rule "ruleY"
when
    yVariable: Y(id==null)
then
    System.out.println( "Y id is null" );
end
```

What I would want to do is to send only a Y object to the server and validate the field "listOfX" with the "ruleX".

Is it possible to say something in ruleY like:

```
rule "ruleY"
when
    yVariable: Y(id==null)
then
   ///validate here with "ruleX" each object of the "listOfX"
    System.out.println( "Y id is null" );
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to use "from" conditional element. See the documentation here [1].

[1] https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.16.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_conditional_element_from

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: See the rule "rule "apply 10% discount to all items over US$ 100,00 in an order"" from the documentation I linked.